# Existing related object is being created again when I save my new EF object

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using code first

I have a Group object that contains a categoryId.
EF creates the Category object and relation.

When I create my group (from a web request), I fetch the cateogry from a repository, searching for the categoryid, then I assign it to the group Category object.

Doing so when I save my group, a new Category is created on the server with a new id, but everything else is the same.

I know they are not from the same context, since the group is new and not attached to a context yet.

The category is created as EntityWrapperWithoutRelationships.

How can I assign the category object, without saving it to EF, since I only need to save the categoryId (which is being saved properly).

Answer (score 0):

If your model looks like this:

```
public class Group 
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Guid CategoryId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CategoryId ")]
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }    
}

public class Category
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}
```

And you have `categoryId` variable which holds valid Category Id, you can create a Group entity with assigned Category like that:

```
_ctx.Groups.Add(new Group() { Name = "name", Id = Guid.NewGuid(), CategoryId = categoryId });
_ctx.SaveChanges();
```

You mentioned, you are using Repositories, so I assume your code will not use DbContext directly.